# Shell programming: How to use find in fish?

Tags: linux, shell, fish

See the following command executed in fish and then bash:

```
tmp ) touch file1 file2 file3 file4
tmp ) find . -exec echo {} \;





tmp ) bash
^_^ ~/tmp > find . -exec echo {} \;
.
./file3
./file2
./file1
./file4
```

Why does fish not understand `echo {} \;`?

Comment: The `{}` is `find` syntax, not shell syntax.  Does `fish` do something special with it?  Have you tried escaping it?

Comment: Aarrrgh and I was wonder wtf.. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to Carl.

`{` and `}` have special meanings in fish. They need to be escaped in order to work with `find`, for example:

`find . -exec echo \{\} \;`

Comment: You can also use find . -exec echo "{}" \;

Answer (score 9):

From the following bug report `'{}'` can also be used which is a tidier syntax in my opinion.

So you would end up with `find . -exec echo '{}' \;`

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/95